# Searching specific websites in Firefox

Tags: firefox, search

On Chrome if I want to search for a video on YouTube I type

`youtube<TAB>`

And I get this:

[image: youtube search screenshot]

Which lets me use YouTube's built in search mechanism rather than searching Google. This same thing works for Amazon and many other non-Google websites.

Does Firefox have an equivalent of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this on Firefox, it requires some [setting up](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar) first.

First go to the site you want and right click on the search bar. I'll use YouTube as an example. In the official Firefox guide linked above they used IMDB. Select **Add a Keyword for this Search...**

[image: Add Keyword]

Then you will get a window asking you to add this as a bookmark. Choose a name and somewhere to save it to. Give it a **keyword**, this will be used to search.

[image: Bookmark]

Now go to the address bar and type the keyword, in this case `youtube`, followed by your query, in this case `test`. You should see the little search/magnifying glass icon appear and the link should be the site's query link.

[image: Test]

It will search the site with your query.

[image: Search]